# Area localisation in MVC with language switcher

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, localization

I have a MVC application with localisation. This has been working great until I added Areas into my application. I have been using this language switcher to switch between available languages.

[image: Language switcher]

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-fit dropdown-menu-right dropdown-menu-anim dropdown-menu-top-unround">
        <ul id="mLangSel" class="kt-nav kt-margin-t-10 kt-margin-b-10">
            <li id="mLangEn" class="kt-nav__item ">
                <a href="@Url.Action("SwitchUICulture","Home",new {lang="en" })" class="kt-nav__link">
                    <span class="kt-nav__link-icon"><img class="rounded-circle" data-offset="10px,0px" src="~/assets/media/flags/012-uk.svg" alt="" /></span>
                    <span class="kt-nav__link-text" style="margin-left:10px">@Menus.MENU_LANG_ENGLISH</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li id="mLangIs" class="kt-nav__item">
                <a href="@Url.Action("SwitchUICulture","Home",new {lang="is-IS" })" class="kt-nav__link">
                    <span class="kt-nav__link-icon"><img class="rounded-circle" style="width:30px;height:auto;" src="~/assets/media/flags/is_iceland.svg" alt="" /></span>
                    <span class="kt-nav__link-text" style="margin-left:10px">@Menus.MENU_LANG_ICELANDIC</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

and here is the Controller method:

```
 public ActionResult SwitchUICulture(string lang)
    {
        //TODO: Add update to UILang claim for user on every change
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lang))
        {
            Session["Culture"] = new CultureInfo(lang);
        }


        return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString()); // RedirectToAction("Index");

    }
```

I also have this method in my Global.cs file

```
 protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (HttpContext.Current.Session != null)
        {

            CultureInfo ci = (CultureInfo)this.Session["Culture"];
            if (ci == null)
            {
                string langName = "en";
                //Try to get values from Accept lang HTTP header
                //if (HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages != null && HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages.Length != 0)
                //{
                //    langName = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages[0].Substring(0, 2);
                //}
                ci = new CultureInfo(langName);
                this.Session["Culture"] = ci;
                this.Session["UiClaim"] = false;
            }
            else
            {
                var lang = ((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).FindFirst(UserClaims.User_Language);

                if (lang!=null && lang.Value!="None" && ci.Name!=lang.Value)
                {
                    if (this.Session["UiClaim"].Equals(false))
                    {
                        ci = new CultureInfo(lang.Value);
                        this.Session["Culture"] = ci;
                        this.Session["UiClaim"] = true;
                    }


                }

            }

            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;

            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(ci.Name);
        }
    }
```

All controllers inherit the base controller where the SwitchUICulture action is.. 
Outide the "Area" everything works great but when I am in a view inside any Area it fails and I get this URL

[image: URL when switching language]

Anyone have a solution to this??

Answer (score 0):

I think path url of you incorrect.Ckeck Url or provide more controller and Areas. I  will help you

Comment: Hello
What do you mean?? This is the URL  I get when using the Lang switcher..

Comment: @Url.Action("SwitchUICulture","Home",new {lang="is-IS" })" is not "Area" Answers Under

Answer (score 0):

This was so simple that the solution was too close :) 
Adding Area = "" to the Url.Action was all it took.

```
    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-fit dropdown-menu-right dropdown-menu-anim dropdown-menu-top-unround">
        <ul id="mLangSel" class="kt-nav kt-margin-t-10 kt-margin-b-10">
            <li id="mLangEn" class="kt-nav__item ">
                <a href="@Url.Action("SwitchUICulture","Home",new {lang="en", area = ""})" class="kt-nav__link">
                    <span class="kt-nav__link-icon"><img class="rounded-circle" data-offset="10px,0px" src="~/assets/media/flags/012-uk.svg" alt="" /></span>
                    <span class="kt-nav__link-text" style="margin-left:10px">@Menus.MENU_LANG_ENGLISH</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li id="mLangIs" class="kt-nav__item">
                <a href="@Url.Action("SwitchUICulture","Home",new {lang="is-IS", area = "" })" class="kt-nav__link">
                    <span class="kt-nav__link-icon"><img class="rounded-circle" style="width:30px;height:auto;" src="~/assets/media/flags/is_iceland.svg" alt="" /></span>
                    <span class="kt-nav__link-text" style="margin-left:10px">@Menus.MENU_LANG_ICELANDIC</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

this is the corrected code snippet